# What is thrift event base and how it's implemented?

Tags: asynchronous, thrift, event-based-programming

I'm starting to use thrift but i couldn't find a good documentation about basic architecture of thrift. The only thing which i know is we have to queue events into eventBase. Can anyone explain more about Thrift EventBase?

Comment: There is a bit of information [in the `lib/cpp` folder README](https://github.com/Jens-G/thrift/tree/master/lib/cpp). As far as I know you have to use the `TNonblockingServer`, but I'm not really into that stuff.

Comment: Apache Thrift supports over 15 languages and each have one or more servers all with different architectures. Can you clarify you specific area of interest and the languages involved?